# Create instance of a class in other project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a .Net solution with two projects. The first project it's a MVC4 application and the second one it's a ClassLibrary project.
I can access to the classes of my MVC4 Projet to my ClassLibrary (like models), but I can't access from my to my ClassLibrary to my MVC4 project to inject a dependency or create an instance.
I'm missing some reference?

Comment: Have you added the required references, first project reference the second and vice versa?

Comment: Just now, no, only the classes are public. What references?

Comment: You can't have both projects reference each other, that is a circular reference. THe usual set up is to have your MVC project reference your class library.

Comment: Then how one project now about the classes contained in the other project. The fact that a class is public means that each consumer of this library, can see this class. Nothing more than this.

Comment: @BenRobinson if you add your comment as an anwer, I''ll check it as correct. Thanks, works, I changed the references and the correct is move the models to the classlibrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a class Library that will be used by an MVC project should be mostly self sufficient, (having dependencies on other libraries etc) but the Library really shouldn't need to know anything about the MVC project.  If that is what you are trying to do, you need to do some redesigning.  Models and other things should be not be a part of the MVC project adding them to the class library would be a better design.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no need to other Classlibrary. You can use all those features in the Model.
2. You can use any dependincy patterns in model like NUnity, Ninject etc. but EntityFramework is always offers Repository pattern as a dipendincy injection with IOC.
3. If you want to use instate of all you can create a sub project and refference it to the model and made your dependincy container control under there.